# Days between current date and a numeric field stored as DDMMYY

Tags: date, db2, days, winsql

I have a field of dates stored as DDDDMMYY and want to calculate the number of days between this date and the current date.

I am using WINSQL and DB2.

I get a result using the below statement

```
days(curdate())-days(date(substr(lsdate+100000000,2,4)||'-'||substr(lsdate+100000000,6,2)||'-'||substr(lsdate+100000000,8,2)))
```

but is it possible to use this as a WHERE clause, ie

```
WHERE days(curdate())-days(date(substr(lsdate+100000000,2,4)||'-'||substr(lsdate+100000000,6,2)||'-'||substr(lsdate+100000000,8,2))) < 10
```

Comment: Add the technology you are using to the tags please.

Comment: why does anyone in the world store a date value NOT in a date typed field?!?

Comment: what is the difference (you expect) between 3112(19)99 and 0101(20)00 or between 0101(19)50 and 0101(20)49?

Comment: "but is it possible to use this as a WHERE clause, ie `WHERE days(curdate())-days(date(substr(lsdate+100000000,2,4)||'-'||substr(lsdate+100000000,6,2)||'-'||substr(lsdate+100000000,8,2))) < 10`" -- Is there any reason not to try this out yourself. Then you should now if it works in a where clause. ... or did you intent to ask a different question?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('d', 'date_column', GetDate()) as difference;
```

SQL has operations to do on date columns and the GetDate() function should give the current date.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying in c# then You can use Total days property for get total day  between two date.

```
int totalDays= (firstDate - secondDate).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

with DDMMYY you are not able to calculate the difference, unless you have some side restrictions. even if you say, the value stored is a birthdate (so it is less than the current date) you have a problem.

say today is 141113 and you want to calculate the difference against 131112. Is the result "1 year and 1 day" or is it "101 years and 1 day". will you send a "welcome-to-the-world package" or a "make-the-rest-of-your-life-happy package"?